# Auto-hide the comment toolbar after an action

Tags: feature-request, comments, design, ios-app

Since (at least) iOS SEß 1.2.2.199, instead of popping up a list of actions, the devs added a little cute bar with four options which shows itself when I click on a comment.

It is the bar just under rene's comment:

[image: The bar under rene's comment]

After an action, like upvoting, I have to manually click the comment to make it hide. No, I'm not too lazy, and as I don't think there are a lot of scenarios where multiple actions should be taken for the same comment, is it possible that after an action, it auto hides?

Comment: It's there for quite a while, at least three versions back as far as I remember,  but I do agree with this request so +1. :)

Comment: Just curious, what did you change in your latest edit? Diff shows nothing and not sure whether it's a bug or not. :/

Comment: @Shadow could it have been edited then retracted in the 5 minute grace? Or is the 5 mins only after original revision

Comment: When edit changes nothing message like "edit was removed during grace period" is displayed. Or should be.